# Is induction the correct approach here?

Tags: real-analysis, induction

Let $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ (real numbers) be such that

$$a_1 - a_2/3 + \dots + (-1)^{n - 1}a_n/(2n - 1) = 0.$$

Prove that

$$f(x):= a_1\cos(x) + a_2\cos(3x) + \dots + a_n\cos([2n - 1]x) = 0,$$

for some $x \in (0, \pi/2)$.

Base case (n = 1): This implies that $a_1 = 0$ (by hypothesis), so that $f(x) = a_1\cos(x) = 0$.

Now assume that the claim holds for $n = k \in \mathbb{N}$. Must show that

$$f(x) = a_1\cos(x) + a_2\cos(3x) + \dots + a_k\cos([2k - 1]x) + a_{k + 1}\cos([2k + 1]x) = 0.$$

By the inductive hypothesis, we have that

$$f(x) = a_1\cos(x) + a_2\cos(3x) + \dots + a_k\cos([2k - 1]x) = 0.$$

Hence,

$$a_{k + 1}\cos([2k + 1]x) = 0.$$

If $a_{k + 1} = 0$, we are done. Suppose not. Then

$$\cos([2k + 1]x) = 0 \implies x = \frac{\pi/2}{2k + 1}.$$

Thus, we have shown that

$$f(x):= a_1\cos(x) + a_2\cos(3x) + \dots + a_n\cos([2n - 1]x) = 0,$$

for some $x \in (0, \pi/2)$.

Are there any analysis tools that one could use to approach this problem differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\frac 1{2k-1}$ smell like integration.
Note that $\int a_k\cos([2k-1]x)\,\mathrm dx=-\frac1{2k-1}\sin([2k-1]x)$.
So consider
$$F(s):=\sum_k \frac{a_k}{2k-1}\sin([2k-1]x)$$
and apply Rolle's theorem

Comment: I'll give it a go.

Comment: Wow, much simpler. Why was the ``1/(2k - 1)" a red light for you to use Rolle's Theorem?